# Google Sheets - Count if two cells have the same text

Tags: google-sheets-formula, string-matching

I'm trying to create a code to see if my predictions for games and the actual result of the games are the same. I was going to create a point value, like March Madness has, but I can't actually get Google Sheets to count if two cells have the same text. I have tried formulas like:
=countif(B14:B15, "*"& N14:N15 &"*") or =countif(B14:B29, "*" & N14:N29 & "*")
=sumproduct(--EXACT(H18,N18))
=Countif(B18:b19,=N18:n19)

I've tried all these formulas, testing them with both matching and non-matching texts just to make sure that it works, but I either get an error or a constant 1 or 0 regardless of what is true or false. I plan on getting a value, then hiding the row and using those values to multiply the total later, but can't seem to get any formula to work with matching the text between two different cells. I've looked at other people with similar issues, but nothing I've tried works.

If there's something I'm missing, please let me know! Thank you

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: I ended up figuring out how to do it. The code I needed for this specific example was:
    =Countif(H18=N18, TRUE)

Comment: You should make your comment an answer and mark it as solved.  That way people who are looking for posts that still need solutions can see that this one has been resolved.